Why is $ n(r) = \frac{dN(r)}{dr} $ positive if the cumulative distribution $ N(r) $ is decreasing?
I’m currently studying the physical characterization of atmospheric aerosols, and I’ve encountered a conceptual problem regarding the particle size distribution.
I understand that $ n(r) \, dr $ represents the number of particles per unit volume with radii between $ r $ and $ r + dr $. The cumulative distribution function $ N(r) $ is defined as the number of particles with radii greater than $ r $:
$$
N(r) = \int_r^{\infty} n(r') \, dr'
$$
This makes $ N(r) $ a monotonically decreasing function, since for larger $ r $, fewer particles are counted (i.e., if $ r_2 > r_1 $, then $ N(r_2) < N(r_1)$).
Now, from the definition of the cumulative distribution, I know that:
$$
n(r) = \frac{dN(r)}{dr}
$$
But here’s my issue: Since $ N(r) $ is decreasing, its derivative should be negative $( \frac{dN(r)}{dr} < 0 $). However, $ n(r) $, representing the number of particles, cannot be negative—it must be positive.
Yet, in my lecture slides, the relationship between $ N(r) $ and $ n(r) $ is presented as:
$$
n(r) = \frac{dN(r)}{dr}
$$
without any negative sign to ensure that $ n(r) $ remains positive.
How can I reconcile the fact that $ N(r) $ is decreasing (thus $ \frac{dN(r)}{dr} < 0 $) with the requirement that $ n(r) $ be positive? Shouldn’t there be a negative sign in front of the derivative?
Thank you in advance for any clarification on this!

Your definition of the cumulative distribution function $N(r)$ is somewhat unusual:
$$
N(r) = \int_r^\infty n(r') dr'
$$
Under this definition, it indeed follows that
$$
\frac{dN(r)}{dr} = -n(r)
$$
Since $r$ is at the bottom of the integral, when you increase $r$, the value of $N(r)$ decreases. So your reasoning about the behavior of $N(r)$ is correct.
Perhaps the best way to resolve the problem is to define $N(r)$ differently. Typically, cumulative distribution functions are defined by adding up the contributions that are less than $r$. In your case, this might look like
$$
N_\text{proper}(r) = \int_0^r n(r') dr'
$$
This will lead to the version of the formula that matches the slide
$$
\frac{dN_\text{proper}(r)}{dr} = n(r)
$$

I find it quite logical to consider the integration limits from 0 to a certain $ r $, as is common in cumulative distribution functions, rather than forcing a negative sign in the definition.
This isn’t such a crucial matter, and, for example, if we hadn’t even specified the integration limits as in Boucher, Olivier, and Boucher's "Atmospheric Aerosols" (Springer Netherlands, 2015, Chapter 3, Section 2), I wouldn't have worried at all. I tend to seek understanding in everything I can.
Thanks. Best regards!
